# Pythonの型ヒントと型アノテーションの違いを教えてください。

Tags: python

## 質問

型ヒント（Type hint）と型アノテーション（Type annotation）の違いを教えてください。

たとえば、「以下の`power`関数の戻りに型ヒントが付いていない」という表現は正しいでしょうか？

```
def power(val: int):
   return val * val
```

型ヒントか型アノテーションかどちらが正しいのか、または同じ意味なのかが分からず、質問しました。

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/typing.html

## 調べたこと

公式ドキュメントの[Type Hint](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-type-hint)には、

> An annotation that specifies the expected type for a variable, a class attribute, or a function parameter or return value.

と書かれているので、型アノテーションより型ヒントの方が広い意味になると思いました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 型ヒント（Type hint）と型アノテーション（Type annotation）の違い

これは、「annotation」という語が多義的であり、文脈が無いと判断できません。現実的にはよく考えずに使用されていることも多いと思いますし、誰も定義していない語だと思います。

#### 包含関係とする用法

「type annotation」は「type hint」（を付与する方法）の一種であり、annotation 構文を用いたものだとする用法があります。これは包含関係であり、質問者さんと同じく

> 型アノテーションより型ヒントの方が広い

という解釈です。

[image: ベン図]

現在、Python の文法に「annotation」が導入されて久しく、「type annotation」という語の「annotation」はその構文を連想させることから、この用法があると思われます。

例:

> So, Type Annotations or Type Comments?
>
> —— [Python Type Checking](https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/#so-type-annotations-or-type-comments)

> It is not allowed for an argument or return value to have both a type annotation and a type comment.
>
> —— [PEP 484 – Type Hints](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code)

> Type hints is a broader category than type annotations.
>
> —— [質問『Disambiguating Python terms, what is the difference between "type hint" vs "type annotations"?』への回答](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/439915)

#### 同等とする用法

上では「type annotation」の「annotation」が構文としての annotation を連想させると述べましたが、もちろんより広い意味での「annotation（注釈）」を意図して書かれることも有るでしょう。この場合、「type hint」と同じ意味で使われて、「type comment（型コメント）」も含むことになります。

[kunifさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/94725/3054)ではこの用法が示されています。しかし、私はこれが唯一の正解では無く、あくまで用法の一つと考えます。

PEP における用法は定まらず、上で例に出したように、包含関係を前提としないと意味が通らない用例もあれば、どちらの解釈でも成り立つ記述もあります。全体的に PEP では「type hint」と「type annotation」の違いは熟慮されておらず、文脈に応じて理解する語として使われていると感じます（上で例として出した質問に[PEP で定義されているというコメント](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/439888/disambiguating-python-terms-what-is-the-difference-between-type-hint-vs-type#comment965638_439888)も有るのですが、私にはそうは読めませんでした）。

#### 将来

将来の可能性として、以下2点があります

- Type comment の廃止が宣言され、type hint を付ける方法は annotation 構文のみになる
- Annotation 構文の利用法は type hint に限ると宣言される

これら（特に前者）が行なわれると、上で述べた二つの用法の違いに意味は無くなります。

#### 「型ヒントが付いていない」という表現

> たとえば、「以下のpower関数の戻りに型ヒントが付いていない」という表現は正しいでしょうか？

これは、上で述べたいずれの用法であっても正しいです。（ただし、示されているコード以外に[スタブファイル](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#stub-files)が存在する可能性が有り、そこに型ヒントが付いているかも知れません）

Answer (score 7):

型ヒント（Type hint）と型アノテーション（Type annotation）は同じものを指し示す別名のようです。
なので「たとえば、「以下のpower関数の戻りに型ヒントが付いていない」という表現は正しいでしょうか？」については「正しい」と思われます。

以下は根拠となる資料です。
[PEP 484 – Type Hints](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/)

> **Rationale and Goals**
> This PEP aims to provide a standard syntax for type annotations,
> この PEP は、型注釈の標準構文を提供することを目的としています。

[PEP 526 – Syntax for Variable Annotations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/)

> **Abstract**
> PEP 484 introduced type hints, a.k.a. type annotations.
> PEP 484 は型ヒント、別名型注釈を導入しました。

上記PEP 484の記述の直前には以下の記述が有ります。

> PEP 3107 added support for arbitrary annotations on parts of a function definition.
> PEP 3107 は、関数定義の一部に任意の注釈のサポートを追加しました。

> Although no meaning was assigned to annotations then, there has always been an implicit goal to use them for type hinting, which is listed as the first possible use case in said PEP.
> 当時は注釈に意味が割り当てられていませんでしたが、型ヒントに注釈を使用するという暗黙の目標が常にありました。

つまり型ヒント（Type hint）の形式で記述されたアノテーション（Annotation）は型アノテーション（Type annotation）と呼べるということでしょう。

質問に紹介された公式ドキュメントのType Hintに書かれていることは、「変数、クラス属性、または関数パラメーターまたは戻り値の予想される型を指定する **アノテーション** 」であるということで、対象となるのは **アノテーション** であって、その記述の中には組み合わせた(あるいは定義される範囲を絞った)単語である「型アノテーション」とは違うとも同じとも書かれていないと思われます。